# Ошибка 'NoneType' object is not callable

Tags: python, telegram-bot

у меня есть простой код для чат бота, но в функции def start(message) выбивает ошибку

```
C:\Users\User\PycharmProjects\pythonProject2\venv\Scripts\python.exe C:/Users/User/PycharmProjects/pythonProject2/main.py
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\User\PycharmProjects\pythonProject2\main.py", line 6, in <module>
    def start(message):
TypeError: 'NoneType' object is not callable

Process finished with exit code 1
```

```
import telebot

bot = telebot.TeleBot("1665714762:AAE2jSQRk9ySK6PdkvZxjFJsttix1QOXJyE")

@bot.message_handler(commands=['help', 'start'])
def start(message):
    send_mess = f"Привет {message.from_user.first_name}  {message.from_user.last_name}!"
    bot.send_message(message.chat.id, send_mess)


def send_welcome(message):
    bot.reply_to(message, "Hi there, I am EchoBot.")


bot.polling(nonstop=True)
```

И даже если я закоментирую первый def, ошибка во во втором. Что я могу сделать что бы не было ошибок?

Comment: приведите в вопросе __весь текст ошибки__ (весь `error traceback`) - в данной формулировке непонятно где возникает ошибка

Comment: Я попробовал ваш код, у меня другая ошибка выходит: `AttributeError: 'TeleBot' object has no attribute 'message_handler'`

Comment: @MaxU я полностью написал код ошибки

Comment: @CrazyElf странно, я весь код взял из сайта телеграмм api

Comment: уберите пустую строку перед def start(message)

Comment: @Влад А библиотеку вы какую ставили? А то бывает подключается одинаково, а ставилась другая вообще библиотека

Comment: @CrazyElf pytelegrambotapi

Comment: а версия библиотеки какая? У меня ваш бот работает вполне себе

Comment: @Влад С этой библиотекой в Google Colab ругается только на `TypeError: polling() got an unexpected keyword argument 'nonstop'`, а если этот параметр убрать, то всё работает

Comment: @Jack_oS Кажется, это не влияет никак всё-таки

Comment: @CrazyElf  nonstop никак не влияет на код, ошибка всеровно всплывает

Comment: @Влад Значит, нужно уточнить версию питона и библиотеки, пока ни у кого ваша ошибка не воспроизвелась.

Comment: @CrazyElf  версия python - 3.9.1 pytelegrambotapi - 3.7.6

Comment: Проверьте после `bot = ` что у вас в этой переменной, напечатайте её `print(bot)`, мне кажется у вас там `None` почему-то.